# Setting Value or Text to an Unknown Element

Tags: jquery, forms, set, element

I'm trying to set the value of an element, if the value can't be set (because it's not an input element such as input, select or textarea) then it must be an element that can be populated with the text()

```
var someval = "My Value";
//Try and set value
$("#some_el").val(someval);
// If it couldn't set
$("#some_el").text(someval);
```

Something like that. Is there a method that will allow me to do this in jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the methods, jQuery checks it internally, so one of the methods will work:

```
$("#some_el").val(someval).text(someval);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Btty/

Another option is checking whether the selected DOM element has a *specific* property like `value` or `textContent` or not, this allows you to use `text` or `val` method as getter:

```
var $elem = $('#some_el'),
    method = 'value' in $elem[0] ? 'val' : 'text';

var value = $elem[method]();
```

Note that this method only works for one selected element, for more that one selected element you can use `.each()` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/hTUnS/

Comment: Just a quick additional question, I'll probably get dinged for this, but does it work as a getter too? I guess I'll find out, but maybe for someone else looking?

Comment: @FelipeTadeo As getter, it throws an error, as the returned string doesn't have `val` or `text` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someval = "My Value";

if($('#some_el').is(':input')){
    $("#some_el").val(someval);
}else{
    $("#some_el").text(someval);
}
```

**Edit**

The `:input` selector can't take advantage of querySelectorAll...so the performance won't be that great; however, that being said, you're using an `id`, so there won't ever be more than one element you're comparing against. if it were more than 1, I'd suggest filtering against it. Normally, I don't recommend the use of non-spec selectors, but here, It's okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someval = "My Value";
$(".someval").each(function () {
    if (typeof $(this)[0].value !== 'undefined') {
        $(this).val(someval);
    } else {
        $(this).text(someval);
    }
});
```

if it can't be set value then the value of attribute is undefined.